Github Action: Push docker image to AWS ECR
I am trying to push a docker image to AWS ECR, below is the my GitHub Action tempalte.
build-and-push-image:
    needs: deploy-infrastructure
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Set up AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-1

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        run: |
          ECR_REPOSITORY=test
          IMAGE_TAG=latest
          IMAGE_NAME=app
          IMAGE_URI="${ECR_REGISTRY}/${ECR_REPOSITORY}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
          docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
          docker tag $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $IMAGE_URI
          docker push $IMAGE_URI

The error occurs at the following line
docker tag $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $IMAGE_URI

Here is the error message
Error parsing reference: "/test:latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


The variable ${ECR_REGISTRY} is not getting populated it seems. Thus the tag command is attempted as docker tag app:latest /test:latest

Looks like there are a few mistakes in your yaml file:

docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG builds and tags the image, so no need to call docker tag afterwards.

the tag doesn't use the full registry, repository and tag name
...
- name: Login to Amazon ECR
  id: login-ecr
  uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

- name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
  id: build-image
  env:
    ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
    ECR_REPOSITORY: test
    IMAGE_TAG: latest
  run: |
    # Build a docker container and
    # push it to ECR so that it can 
    # be deployed to ECS.
    docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
    docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG



